# Large PNG Images in iPhone App Dev

Tags: iphone, performance, image, compression

I have a question about the png images I am using in my iPhone app. I have a lot of large images for different views, they are compressed but I was wondering if that would slow down the application at all. Like in initial loading time and loading different views Basically I need to know how to make the app smaller in size and faster by just adjusting the images? Or if it is even worth it to mess with that?

I HAVE done research on this topic but I haven't found any viable solutions besides compressing the images.

Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: Suggestion: Don't ever use larger images in terms of resolution, not in terms of size. If the image has larger resolution than the iphone screen, eventhough it is compressed by interface builder it will creates a large mess in the application.

Answer (score 2):

Hope, this helps !!!

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7307-resizing-photo-new-uiimage.html

```
      -(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image {

CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

int width, height;

width = 640;
height = 480;

CGContextRef bitmap;

if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp | image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);

} else {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, height, width, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);

}

if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    NSLog(@"image orientation left");
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -height);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    NSLog(@"image orientation right");
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -width, 0);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
    NSLog(@"image orientation up"); 

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    NSLog(@"image orientation down");   
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, width,height);
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-180.));

}

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return result;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When you use your app, do you notice slow loading times? If not then don't bother messing with the images, the gains will be minimal if at all.

If you are having problems with loading times on your app then don't assume it is the PNGs. Use the tools provided and profile your app to find out what the slow parts are and start from there. Never assume you know what the cause of slow code is.

Comment: This I do know. I was just wondering what possible solutions would be for large images.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question though.